# JSF h:commandLink not work with filter

Tags: jsf-2, servlet-filters

I create simple login system for my jsf project.
In project I create filter to check user login status.

- If login, continue to requested page.
- If not login or session is destroy, redirect to login page

My problem is, if I apply filter then all of h:commandLink not process anything after clicked. But when I remove filter, everything work well.

I try to use h:commandButton with fileter, then everthing work correctly.

How can I fixed this problem?
I research for a long time, but not found any solution.
Please help me!

Filter code:

```
    @WebFilter(filterName = "AuthenticationFilter", urlPatterns = {"*.htm"}, dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.REQUEST})
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    // The filter configuration object we are associated with.  If
    // this value is null, this filter instance is not currently
    // configured. 
    private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;

    @Inject
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;  

    public AuthenticationFilter() {
    } 

    /**
     * @param request The servlet request we are processing
     * @param response The servlet response we are creating
     * @param chain The filter chain we are processing
     *
     * @exception IOException if an input/output error occurs
     * @exception ServletException if a servlet error occurs
     */
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        Throwable problem = null;        
        try {
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request; 
            String requestUrl = req.getRequestURI(); 

            String contextPath = req.getContextPath(); 
            if(contextPath.equals("/")){
                contextPath = "";
            }
            String jsfUrl = requestUrl.replaceFirst(contextPath, "");

            if (authenticationManager.allowedAccess(jsfUrl) || requestUrl.equalsIgnoreCase(contextPath+"/login.htm")) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);                
            } 
            else {
                String redirectPath = contextPath+"/login.htm";
                ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(redirectPath); // Not logged in, so redirect to error page.
            }
        } 
        catch (Throwable t) {
            // If an exception is thrown somewhere down the filter chain,
            // we still want to execute our after processing, and then
            // rethrow the problem after that.
            problem = t;
        }

        // If there was a problem, we want to rethrow it if it is
        // a known type, otherwise log it.
        if (problem != null) {
            if (problem instanceof ServletException) {
                throw (ServletException) problem;
            }
            if (problem instanceof IOException) {
                throw (IOException) problem;
            }
            sendProcessingError(problem, response);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the filter configuration object for this filter.
     */
    public FilterConfig getFilterConfig() {
        return (this.filterConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Set the filter configuration object for this filter.
     *
     * @param filterConfig The filter configuration object
     */
    public void setFilterConfig(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {        
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {        
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
        if (filterConfig != null) {
        }
    }
}
```

Jsf code:

```
<h:body>
<f:view contentType="text/html" locale="#{authenticationManager.languageCode}">
<div class="header">
    <h:form id="topForm" prependId="false">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><img src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/images/login-logo2.png" width="220" height="64"/></h1>
        </div>  
        <ul class="navTop">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span class="pictograms">f</span>#{authenticationManager.currentUser.firstName} #{authenticationManager.currentUser.lastName}</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span class="pictograms">m</span>Messages</a>
            </li>
            <li class="logout">
                <h:commandButton action="#{authenticationManager.logout()}" value="aaaaaaa" style="color:#fff;" />
                <h:commandLink action="#{authenticationManager.logout()}" value="#{label.Logout}"/>
                <h:commandLink immediate="true" action="#{authenticationManager.logout}" id="logoutLink">
                    <span class="pictograms">E</span>***This link is not work correctly***
                </h:commandLink>
            </li>
        </ul>           
        <ui:insert name="mainmenu"/>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your concrete problem is caused because the serving of the JSF default resource `jsf.js` has been blocked by the filter. This resource is mandatory for functioning of JSF command links and JSF ajax requests (plain command buttons without ajax will just work).

You need to exclude JSF resources from the authentication check. You can do that by just checking if the request URI starts after the webapp context path with [`ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html#RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER) (which has a value of `/javax.faces.resource`).

So, basically:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

if (req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response); // Let it continue.
    return;
}
```

Checking the file extensions is clumsy and does not sufficiently cover all possible resource requests.

Answer (score 0):

After research, I didn't found any solution.
So I guest to many possible ways, and found the explanation about this.

I filter everything with filter pattern "*.htm", then every request like .js.htm, .css.htm, .gif.htm, .jpg.htm will redirected to login.htm page.

The point is redirect .js.htm to login page instead of right file.
So the important library like jsf.js.htm was redirect to login.htm, this is the main cause to make h:commandLink work not correctly.

Hop this will help someone, like me.

```
try {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request; 
        String requestUrl = req.getRequestURI(); 

        if(requestUrl.endsWith(".js.htm") 
            || requestUrl.endsWith(".css.htm") 
            || requestUrl.endsWith(".gif.htm") 
            || requestUrl.endsWith(".png.htm") 
            || requestUrl.endsWith(".jpg.htm") 
            || requestUrl.endsWith(".jpeg.htm")){
            chain.doFilter(request, response);            
        }
        else{
            String contextPath = req.getContextPath(); 
            if(contextPath.equals("/")){
                contextPath = "";
            }
            String jsfUrl = requestUrl.replaceFirst(contextPath, "");

            if (authenticationManager.allowedAccess(jsfUrl) || requestUrl.equalsIgnoreCase(contextPath+"/login.htm")) {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);                
            } 
            else {
                String redirectPath = contextPath+"/login.htm";
                ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(redirectPath); // Not logged in, so redirect to error page.
            }
        }
    }
```